# Retilizar Plantilla Word desde vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

Tengo una plantilla de Word de una página, se requiere generar cartas de aviso a clientes, ¿cómo puedo usar la plantilla para que me tire una carta por cliente en un mismo documento de word?

Comment: Hola Medardo, deberías editar la pregunta para añadir algo más de detalles. No termina de quedar claro qué es lo que quieres o qué hace el código compartido (o si tiene relación con la pregunta en sí). Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: Gracias, me Explico y disculpen, tengo una plantilla en word de una sola pagina y un listado de clientes, donde quiero generar cartas de aviso, esto puede ser mas de dos cartas en un mismo documento, pero tengo el problema que no se como hacerlo por que al momento de hacer la segunda carta ya los parametros o marcadores no existen. como puedo crear un documento de varias paginas reutilizando la plantilla?